# php / mysql list function not returning anything! help!

Tags: php, mysql, list

Is there any reason why this would not return anything?

```
list($price) = mysql_query(sprintf("select price from product where productid_FK = ".$productid"));
```

I have used the list function on another page and is working fine, not sure why it is not returning anything on this page.

I have outputted the sql code and ran it in mysql and it worked fine. Please note that this query is in a while loop.

Thanks

Comment: What do you use `list()` for?

Comment: Not exactly sure how efficient it is, but is a quick way of getting the result of the query to the var $price.

Comment: you should provide more complete code... this one line would not only fail to work, but also is very wrong application of list() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_query() returns a ressource, not an array.
You need to use mysql_fetch_array() or similar to get something  that list() can work with.

Comment: My apologies I have actually been using mysql_fetch_row around the code which I omitted when copying and pasting. Also tried mysql_fetch_array with no success.

Comment: Arrrghhhhhhh my mistake sorry all I made a mistake and put productid_FK instead of productid in my query.

Thanks

Comment: Here's the code that I am using:

list($price) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(sprintf("select price from product where productid = ".$productid")));


Thanks Dr. Molle